# javascript regexp: match everything after :: but not >

Tags: javascript, regex

I created this regex: `/[::].+[^\>]/g`

Test:

```js
let str = "<foo::bar>"
let match = str.match(/[::].+[^\>]/g).join('')
console.log(match)
```

Expected answer : `bar`

Actual answer : `::bar`

Answers appreciated.

Comment: `[::]` is a character class that matches only one colon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use a capturing group instead of a lookbehind:

```
::([^>]+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NABG3G/1)

For example

```js
const regex = /::([^>]+)/g;
const str = `<foo::bar>`;
let m;
let match = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  match.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(match.join(''));
```

---

If you want to match the whole pattern of the string, you might use:

```
<[^>]+::([^>]+)>
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ycimYY/1)

```js
const regex = /<[^>]+::([^>]+)>/g;
const str = `<foo::bar>`;
let m;
let match = [];

while ((m = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  match.push(m[1]);
}
console.log(match.join(''));
```

Comment: the most documented answer... Appreciate you. Actually this regex thing is going for my new project [teddytags](https://github.com/obnoxiousnerd/teddytags). A library for serving you custom elements, with support as far as IE9*.

Answer (score 4):

One option is to use a lookbehind assertion (`(?<=)`), which is currently supported only by Chrome & Safari:

```js
const str = "<foo::bar>"

const match = str.match(/(?<=::)[^\>]+/g).join('')

console.log(match)
```

Comment: [lookbehind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) is a new feature, and is not supported by all web browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Adding an extra match & join to remove '::' had solved the problem.

**Working code:**

```
let str = "<foo::bar>"
let match = str.match(/[::].+[^\>]/g).join('')
            .match(/[^(::)].+/g).join()
console.log(match)
```

Comment: `[::]` is a character class that matches only one colon.

Comment: Thank you. I just verified that enclosing the two colons in parenthesis - "match(/[^(::)].+/g).join()" - is also working.